# SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl"

Tags: php, ssl, pear

I've been trying to get to be able to send emails with Pear on WAMP *through GMail*, and after spending hours setting it all up and figuring out all the errors I was getting, I thought I was so close, until I started getting this error:

```
Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (code: -1, response: )]
```

Using this code:

```
<?php require_once "info.php"; require_once "Mail.php"; // info.php contains the variable $password
$from = "Me <myemail@gmail.com>";
$to = "Me <myemail@gmail.com>";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "465";
$username = "myemail@gmail.com";
$password = "$password";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
 'port' => $port,
 'auth' => true,
 'username' => $username,
 'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
?>
```

I've gone through and uncommented `extension=php_openssl.dll` in the (correct) php.ini, and made sure that the `extension_dir` was pointing to the DLLs.  I've used `phpinfo();` and I've seen multiple mentions of SSL:

I see `mod_ssl` in `Loaded Modules`.

Under the `mysqlnd` heading it has an entry `SSL: supported`.

And under the `Phar` heading there's the entry `Native OpenSSL support: enabled`.

I've also turned off my firewall, just to check, I've restarted my computer, and I've checked practically every question like mine on this site, and I still haven't found a solution.

I'm at a loss of what to do next.  What do I need to enable/check to get it working?

Answer (score 4):

Open up the Port 465 open to smtp.gmail.com in your firewall :)

[This will help](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/open-a-port-in-windows-firewall)

Then there may be problem with your host or else,

[Try This](http://eftakhairul.com/send-email-using-smtp-authentication-by-php-pear-package/) - this is working for me

Did you allow SMTP in your Gmail

Check that 'Settings' is active for the SMTP server in your Gmail Settings.

Comment: I said near the end that I had my firewall completely off.  I tried that anyway, though, yet it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not using Ubuntu (though I have it), I'm using Windows 7.  I've also checked all the settings in GMail once more, and everything was okay.  Thank you for taking the time, I hope I can figure this out. :)

Comment: @Flappy,Can you tell me the solution for the above problem.I am struggling in the same problem.

Comment: @BABUK, i opened the port 465 in the firewall, that solved the problem.

Comment: @Flappy,OK.I try and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

Uncoment **`php_openssl.dll`** in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

The answer was simple; The first thing you should do:

1. Open the file `php.ini` then try to search the key `extension`. Then if you cannot find this `extension=php_openssl.dll` and please write it but make sure you remove `;` before the word `extension`.
2. Once you save it, please restart again your Xampp server. After that, everything is good.

Comment: As I stated in the question I had already done that.  I ended up doing something else anyway because I never got it to work, though I don't even remember exactly what this was for.